# Create a dynamic function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe with 7 columns. The 3 columns Product, Original Price and New Price are self explanatory. Then, Q1-Q4 are average **projected** prices over 4 quarters.

What you will see in these columns are codes e.g. DN1, DG1, DN2 etc. These codes have values associated with them but the values are irrelevant for this exercise i.e. they could be anything.

For Q1 - Q4, each cell value is calculated using a formula e.g. projected price for Product A in Q1 = DN1+1. So if DN1= 3, then projected price is 3+1 = 4. Similar logic is followed and each value in Q1-Q4 for all products is calculated based on formulas.

How do I edit my function to make it more dynamic/efficient in the sense that should the formulas change, I am able to easily make that change e.g. if formula for projected price for Product D in Q2 changes, I should be able to make that change easily without having to go and amend the code.

I was hoping to perhaps use an excel/csv that will look something like this:

```
Cell         Formula    Period
Value[1]     =DN1+1      Q1
Value[2]     =DK1        Q2
Value[3]     =DK1        Q3
Value[4]     =DK1        Q4
Value[5]     =DN2+3 (this value e.g. changed from DN2)
```

All i would then have to do is, make the change in the formula in the appropriate cell in the excel file and pass the csv/excel through the function to get the output.

Reproducible code for my dataframe:

```
    Q1<-c("=DN1+1","=DN2+3","=DN3*4","=DN4-1","=DN1 + DN2 + DN3 + DN4") 
    Q2<-c("=DK1", "=DK2","=DN3+DK3","=DN4+DL3- DM1 * ( DM2 + ((-DJ7-DK3) / S20+ S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)","=DG1 + DG2 + DG3 + DG4")
    Q3<-c("=DK1","=DK2","=DG3 (-1 qtr) +DK3","=DG4(-1 qtr)+DL3- DM1 * ( DM2 + ((-DJ7-DK3) / S20+ S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)","=DG1 + DG2 + DG3 + DG4")
    Q4<-c("=DK1","=DK2","DG3 (-1 qtr) +DK3","=DG4(-1 qtr)+DL3- DM1 * ( DM2 + ((-DJ7-DK3) / S20+ S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)","DG1 + DG2 + DG3 + DG4")
    D1<-data.frame(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
    D1$Product<-c("A","B","C","D","Total")
    D1$Original_Price<-c("DN1","DN2","DN3","DN4","DN7")
    D1$New_Price<-c("DG1","DG2","DG3","DG4","DG7")
    D1<-D1[,c(5,6,7,1,2,3,4)]
```

Reproducible code for function: Currently, the formulas are all hardcoded. This function takes a dataframe as an input/argument which contains two columns 1.) Column for codes e.g. DN1, DN2 etc. 2.) Column for values associated with codes e.g. 22 (value for DN1), 48 (value for DN2)..etc.

```
function_1<-function(dta)
{
Product <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","Total","Total","Total","Total")
Original_Price <- c("DN1","DN1","DN1","DN1","DN2","DN2","DN2","DN2","DN3","DN3","DN3","DN3","DN4","DN4","DN4","DN4","DN7","DN7","DN7","DN7")
New_Price <- c("DG1","DG1","DG1","DG1","DG2","DG2","DG2","DG2","DG3","DG3","DG3","DG3","DG4","DG4","DG4","DG4","DG7","DG7","DG7","DG7")
Period <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
Value <- c("n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a")
for (i in c (1:nrow(dta))) {
    assign(as.character(dta[i,1]), dta[i,2])
    print(dta[i,1])
    print ("_")
    print(dta[i,2])
}

Value[1] <- DN1+1
Value[2] <- DK1
Value[3] <- DK1
Value[4] <- DK1
Value[5] <- DN2   
Value[6] <- DK2
Value[7] <- DK2
Value[8] <- DK2
Value[9] <- DN3
Value[10] <- DN3 + DK3
Value[11] <- as.numeric(Value[10]) + DK3
Value[12] <- as.numeric(Value[11]) + DK3
Value[13] <- DN4
Value[14] <- DN4+DL3- DM1 * ( DM2 + ((-DJ7-DK3) / S20+ S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)
Value[15] <- as.numeric(Value[14]) + DL3 - DM1 * ( DM2 + ((0 -DJ7-DK3) / S20 + S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)
Value[16] <- as.numeric(Value[15]) + DL3 - DM1 * ( DM2 + ((0 -DJ7-DK3) / S20 + S22) + S223 + Y446 / ZQ282 - W223)
Value[17] <- DN1 + DN2 + DN3 + DN4 
Value[18] <- as.numeric(Value[2]) + as.numeric(Value[6]) + as.numeric(Value[10]) + as.numeric(Value[14]) 
Value[19] <- as.numeric(Value[3]) + as.numeric(Value[7]) + as.numeric(Value[11]) + as.numeric(Value[15]) 
Value[20] <- as.numeric(Value[4]) + as.numeric(Value[8]) + as.numeric(Value[12]) + as.numeric(Value[16])
output <- data.frame(Product,Original_Price,New_Price,Period,Value)
 }
```

UPDATE:
How do I amend the code to replace the hard-coded reference to previous quarter values e.g. `Value[11] <- as.numeric(Value[10]) + DK3`

I coded the function on the assumption the values will be provided with a suffix, but the data is being received by quarter meaning the same cell code will repeat 4 times (once for each quarter) i.e.

```
Code Value Period
DN1  200    Q1
DN1  300    Q2
DN1  400    Q3
DN1  500    Q4
```

So my function will fail since it won't pick up correct values.

Comment: Can anybody help with this ?

Comment: you should make your example **minimal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here, but this is how I understood it.. You have a table where each cell's content is calculated according to a specific column. You want to be able to update the formulas and recalculate the values within your table, without hardcoding everything.

My solution would be to write a function where you supply a table to be updated AND a table where each cell is the formula that you want to use. The formulas have to be written down as characters. You then can use `eval(parse())` to make this work.

Let's try:

```
# Create data and a formula data frame
x <- 10
y <- 5

forms <- c("x + y", 
           "x - y", 
           "x / y", 
           "x * y")

form_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(forms, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), stringsAsFactors = F)
#      V1    V2
# 1 x + y x / y
# 2 x - y x * y

df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(15,6), col2 = c(50,50))
#   col1 col2
# 1   15   50
# 2    6   50

# Create a function that creates a data frame from this
dyndf <- function(x, y, df_old, form_df) {
             df_new <- sapply(form_df,function(z1) sapply(z1, function(z2) eval(parse(text=z2))))
             df_old[df_new != df_old] <- df_new[df_new != df_old]
             df_old
}

dyndf(x,y,df1,form_df)

#   col1 col2
# 1   15    2
# 2    5   50
```

Some explanations... The function is not that complicated, but basically we take the formula data frame, we evaluate every function in each cell and create a new data frame. This new data frame looks horrible because it lacks column names and other kinds of information. So, we simply check which values are updated, and then overwrite those.

By rewriting the function, you can probably make it fit your own problem.

Edit: A quick example of a vector where any element may rely on the previous elements...

```
vec <- 1:5
forms <- c("1 + 1", "vec[1] + 2", "vec[1] * vec[2]", "vec[3] / vec[1]", "vec[5]")

for (i in 1:length(vec)) vec[i] <- eval(parse(text=forms[i]))

vec
# [1] 2 4 8 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks Laterow - your suggestion worked. But there was some slight change in the problem due to change in data source structure. I've updated the description. Any help is appreciated

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to be able to work with previously updated values. Try a `for` loop instead (see edit above). Since `for` loops update one element at a time, you can use this instead. It's a bit slower than `sapply`, but it works. If this answers your question, don't forget to press the check mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Not sure how this would work with the format I have - code, value and quarter. I have about 300 cells for which I have to calculate values. Where there is a reference to previous quarter, it must look at the code AND the quarter and then input the value

Comment: Oh... Then for those cells, just provide a formula that subsets the right element of the `value` column? `a[a$Code=="DN1" & a$Period=="Q1","Value"]`? This whole question is starting to look like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)..

Comment: I think I should start a new question for this. Thanks for your help